# Joining Lists using Linq returns different result than corresponding SQL query?

Tags: c#

I have 2 tables

TableA:

```
TableAID int,
Col1 varchar(8)
```

TableB:

```
TableBID int
Col1 char(8),
Col2 varchar(40)
```

When I run a SQL query on the 2 tables it returns the following number of rows

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableA (7200 rows)
select * FROM tableB (28030 rows)
```

When joined on col1 and selects the data it returns the following number of rows

```
select DISTINCT a.Col1,b.Col2 FROM tableA a
join tableB b on a.Col1=b.Col1 (6578 rows)
```

The above 2 tables on different databases so I created 2 EF models and retried the data separately and tried to join them in the code using linq with the following function. Surprisingly it returns 2886 records instead of 6578 records. Am I doing something wrong?
The individual lists seems to return the correct data but when I join them SQL query and linq query differs in the number of records.

Any help on this greatly appreciated.

```
// This function is returning 2886 records      
public List<tableC_POCO_Object> Get_TableC() 
{
    IEnumerable<tableC_POCO_Object> result = null;
    List<TableA> tableA_POCO_Object = Get_TableA(); // Returns 7200 records
    List<TableB> tableB_POCO_Object = Get_TableB(); // Returns 28030 records
    result = from tbla in tableA_POCO_Object
         join tblb in tableB_POCO_Object on tbla.Col1 equals tblb.Col1
         select new tableC_POCO_Object 
         {
         Col1 = tblb.Col1,
         Col2 = tbla.Col2
         };
    return result.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Does it matter that in linq you are returning
tblb.Col1, and tbla.Col2, but in your SQL you are doing tbla.Col1 and tblb.Col2?

Comment: No it doesn't, I tried those combinations.

Comment: tableC_POCO_Object only contains the two properties Col1 and Col2?

Comment: Yes you are correct, even if I return tableA_POCO_Object or tableB_POCO_Object the number of records returned remained same.

Comment: So, befre returning  try doing:

`var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)result).ToTraceString();` and see what the sql is.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute, I just read your code a little more closely. You are getting both tables and MANUALLY joining them. Yeah, in that case, the probably is case sensitivity.

Comment: Yes, I need to get my tables separately and join them in the code. I tried recommendations from other friends here with out any luck. Not sure what is the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the help , my .Trim did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the fact that in your POCO world, you're trying to compare two strings using a straight comparison (meaning it's case-sensitive). That might work in the SQL world (unless of course you've enabled case-sensitivity), but doesn't quite work so well when you have `"stringA" == "StringA"`. What you should do is normalize the join columns to be all upper or lower case:

```
join tblb in tableB_POCO_Object on tbla.Col1.ToUpper() equals tblb.Col1.ToUpper()
```

Join operator creates a lookup using the specified keys (starts with second collection) and joins the original table/collection back by checking the generated lookup, so if the hashes ever differ they will not join.

Point being, joining OBJECT collections on string data/properties is bad unless you normalize to the same cAsE. For LINQ to some DB provider, if the database is case-insensitive, then this won't matter, but it always matters in the CLR/L2O world.

Edit: Ahh, didn't realize it was `CHAR(8)` instead of `VARCHAR(8)`, meaning it pads to 8 characters no matter what. In that case, `tblb.Col1.Trim()` will fix your issue. However, still keep this in mind when dealing with LINQ to Objects queries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried the above with out any luck, and still no change in the number of records returned.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because you compare a `VARCHAR` and a `CHAR` column. In SQL, this depends on the settings of `ANSI_PADDING` on the sql server, while in C# the string values are read using the DataReader and compared using standard string functions.

Try `tblb.Col1.Trim()` in your LINQ statement.

Answer (score 0):

As SPFiredrake correctly pointed out this can be caused by case sensitivity, but I also have to ask you why did you write your code in such a way, why not this way:

```
// This function is returning 2886 records      
public List<tableC_POCO_Object> Get_TableC() 
{
    return from tbla in Get_TableA()
           join tblb in Get_TableB() on tbla.Col1 equals tblb.Col1
           select new tableC_POCO_Object 
           {
             Col1 = tblb.Col1,
             Col2 = tbla.Col2
           }.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

where Get_TableA() and Get_TableB() return IEnumerable instead of List. You have to watch out for that, because when you convert to list the query will be executed instantly. You want to send a single query to the database server.

Comment: sure, point noted will make changes to the code as advised. But my original problem remains unresolved.